# Comparing character of an array to a string

Tags: java

What's the best way to compare character of an array to a string.

```
    import java.io.Console;
    class msd{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Console console= System.console();
    String letter="Hello";
    String[] Arrayname=letter.split("");

    if(Arrayname[0] == "H")
    console.printf("success");
    else
    console.printf("failure");
    }
   }
```

Output

```
    failure
```

Expecting to be success.

Comment: You're better off using the `charAt()` method rather then splitting the string. E.g. `letter.charAt(0) == 'H'`

Comment: You can use String.substring() and equals method. For your case, you can use Arrayname.substring(0,1).equals("H") condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `equals` method to do so:

```
Arrayname[0].equals("H")
```

The `==` operator compares references not values.